# add metadata extractor to project without nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, metadata-extractor

Due to some project needs I will need to add metadata extractor to my project without using Nuget(as I cannot use the VS package manager). I am having trouble adding it as an external project. What is the best way to add it externally without using Nuget ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet allows you to download packages:

On this page (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetadataExtractor/):

[image]

That will download a `.nupkg` file, which you can rename to `.zip` then find the `.dll` file inside.

You'd need to do the same things for any dependencies.

Honestly if you could use NuGet it'd be much easier for you. But that is the workaround.